# PHP: html tidy repair string: making it not encase everything in <html>

Tags: php, html, htmltidy

Using the following code:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$clean = $tidy->repairString("<p>Hello</p>");
```

This encases the string in the whole shenanigans:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I'm using it on a "description" field, containing some html tags from time to time, I just want to use it to fix anomalies in the string, forexample unclosed elements, elements that are closed but not opened and so on, not encase it like this as a full html document.

If the string doesnt contain any html at all, it should just return the input. And if it contains html like the example above, it should fix whatever there is to fix, (which is nothing in this example) and not encase it in a full document.

Anyone know how to make HTML Tidy not encase it like this?

Comment: Per http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php the second parameter takes an array of options. I'd try `array('doctype' => false, 'output-html' => false)` but somehow I doubt it will work. (Sorry, don't have tidy enabled right now to try it)

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with the same problem. But found it in the tidy documentation. If you add 'show-body-only' => true it will not show the complete html header and so on.

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$input = "<p>A paragraph with <b>bold<b> text";
$clean = $tidy->repairString($input,array('show-body-only' => true));
echo $clean;
```

will show:`<p>A paragraph with <b>bold</b> text</p>`

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. To do the same in procedural style, just do:
`echo tidy_repair_string($input, array('show-body-only' => true));`